# How do I find an event to an action in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudtrail

Is there an obvious way to know, what action for example the management console leads to what event, which I could look up in couldtrail?

I want basically change a security group and find the corresponding event ModifySecurityGroupRule, but for every event.

Comment: You should be able to work out which API calls to use for a specific action by reading the relevant SDK and API documentation. If you really want to know which APIs the AWS console is calling then generally you can use CloudTrail to determine that.

Answer (score 1):

The event name in CloudTrail usually corresponds to the name of the action used in IAM policies. The easiest way I found to figure out the action name is to let the console tell you when you lack permissions. This sounds awkward but, trust me, finding the actions can sometimes be tricky. The first step is to remove some permissions or add some `deny` statements to make your console action fail. Then perform the action in the web console. In this case, I'm trying to edit an inbound rule in a security group. You can see in the screenshot below the error message shows that the required permission is `ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules`.

[image]